Getting error "validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>."
Here's my code

const ReadMore = ({children}) => {
    const text = children;
    const [isReadMore, setIsReadMore] = useState(true);
    const toggleReadMore = () => {
        setIsReadMore(!isReadMore);
    };
    return (
        <>
          <p className={`text ${!isReadMore ? "expanded" : ""}`}>
              {isReadMore  ? text[0] : text}
              <span
                  onClick={toggleReadMore}
                  className={`read-or-hide ${!isReadMore ? "expanded" : ""}`}
                  style={{ color: "#00ADB5", cursor: 'pointer'}}
              >  
                  {isReadMore ? "Position Activities" : " show less"}
              </span>
          </p>
        </>
    );
  };
  
  export default function Experience() {
    
    return (
      <>
        <div className='main_div_experience_section'>
          <div className='experience_h1'>
            <span className='text-6xl font-bold text-white'>
              Experience
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className='parent_section'>
            <div className='rectangle'>
              <div className='grid'>
                <div className='col1'>
                  <div className='years_experience'><p>Sep 2023 - Present</p></div>
                </div>
                <div className='col2'>
                  <div className='text_company'>
                    <div className='grouper_name_and_logo'>
                      <div className='img_div_experience'>
                          <a href="home">
                            <img src={Nymbus} alt="" className='company_img_experience' href="home"/>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                      <h1 className='role_experience text-gray-400 text-xl font-normal'>
                        Full Stack Developer - asdfasdf
                      </h1>
                    </div>
                    <ReadMore>
                      <div className={`role_explanation_experience`}>
                        <ul>
                          <p className='my_p_experience'>Daily Activities:</p>
                          <li>SOMETHING</li>
                          <li>SOMETHING</li>
                          <li>SOMETHING</li>
                          <li>SOMETHING</li>
                          <li>SOMETHING</li>
                          <li>SOMETHING</li>
                          <li>SOMETHING</li>
                          <li>SOMETHING</li>
                          <p className='following_p_experience'>Achievements:</p>
                          <li>SOMETHING</li>
                          <li>SOMETHING</li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </ReadMore>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }

The function ReadMore is basically a read more section that can increase or decrease by clicking on the <p> tag. However, I've been getting the warning "Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <ul> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>." and I'd like to fix that.
Furthermore, I'd like to add the functionality to add a transition for my ReadMore function, but I just can't get it to work, I've been thinking is because of the warning (maybe?)
I'd pretty much appreciate your help or recommendations.
I've tried

Modified ReadMore function
Added CSS for transition functionality


Im sorry, but what exactly is not clear with that warning message? Your ReadMore components wraps the content you pass to it (children) in a React.Fragment (<> </>) and inside of <p> </p> element, which is basically not a valid html according to html5 spec. Why is it <p> inside of ReadMore? Why not <div>...</div>? Why not anything else? And regardless css for transition - can you post the css you tried to use to create the transition so we can reproduce it and suggest a fix?

Next question - what is text[0] inside of your ReadMore component? Have you tried to console log the text and text[0] with the exact children you have for ReadMore component inside of Experience component? You are not passing an array of elements as a children parameter, you are passing one div element that has children nodes, so text[0] is undefined. Is that the thing that is "not working"?

Hi @SergeySosunov, you were right, channging  to  fixed all the issues I was having. The styling that I have tried for the transition is:
.expanded {
transition: margin-bottom width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
}
But checking on devtools in the styling I have a warning "invalid property value".
